# How to setup VPN to trust specific expired certificate

Tags: vpn, certificates

The certificate for a specific vpn server I need to be accessing has expired. It is a server from my work, and I keep bugging our overloaded admin to update it. So far and until he does, I have to always tell ubuntu I "know what I am doing" but sometimes I am in a hurry and do not fully check that it looks correct, so this is a potential problem.

I know and trust the holder of the certificate even though its expired, but have no control to change the expired certificate. Is there a way to set this particular certificate as trusted? I understand this is a bad idea, but the alternative solution is also a bad idea.

I think am using what should be the default for Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS,  (Set it up from settings-->Network--> VPN <clicked `+`> with protocol `VPN Protocol being Cisco AnyConnect or openconnect`)
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you using to connect to this VPN?

Comment: the default available, with openconnect i think... added 2 screenshots

Comment: Expired certificates cannot be trusted when using AnyConnect - it's an issue that you can't override on the local side of things.  AnyConnect / OpenConnect spec details that the certificate has to be valid to work.  The SSL checks are hardcoded into the protocol and client, and can't be overridden globally.

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve the issue 100%,
but in my case I used the command line to connect to the vpn:

```
sudo openconnect -u myusername myserver.foo.bar
```

Then got the answer:

```
POST https://myserver.foo.bar/
Connected to xxx.xxx.xx.xx:443
SSL negotiation with myserver.foo.bar
Server certificate verify failed: certificate expired

Certificate from VPN server "myserver.foo.bar" failed verification.
Reason: certificate expired
To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
    --servercert pin-sha256:JsDBYfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarE+z2adHg=
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view:
```

Then `ctrl-C` and was able to connect with:

```
sudo openconnect -u myusername myserver.foo.bar --servercert pin-sha256:JsDBYfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarE+z2adHg=
```